# #Multitask# Training two tasks based on shared features leads to one task failed to converge, but spliting the features for training works fine. How?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, unsupervised-learning

[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ0Ed.jpg)

Dear all, I encountered the above problem concerning multi-task learning. What does this phenomenon indicate? Does it mean the upper-most features contribute little to the main task? And what lesson perhaps can I get from it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Qichao Ying and welcome to StackOverflow, I'm afraid this question is off-topic here.

Comment: That being said, I might suggest that your loss components are unbalanced. Weight the loss component that is failing to converge higher and higher relative to the other task until performance meaningfully changes. That should hopefully give you a good starting point of where to analyze next